# Retrieve Google OAuth App rating programmatically

Tags: google-apps, google-apps-marketplace, google-workspace

would like to try out the recently added G-Suite admin feature where one can whitelist third party OAuth apps using a test G-Suite account:

https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2017/07/manage-access-to-third-party-apps-with.html

In order to determine if an app should be added in the list or not, I would like to retrieve app ratings programatically. How can I retrieve ratings and installation count for a Google OAuth App programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think doing this programatically is supported as of now. No mention of such in [G Suite Marketplace docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/overview). You can request a new feature [here](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=191597&template=823911).